# Where does energy go?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation, interferometry

Where  does energy go?

Given is the Michelson interferometer. One sends light in
in the form of a plane wave $E_0\exp[i(kx-wt)]$ into the interferometer.

The position of one of the mirrors is adjusted in such a way,
so that at the output of the interterometer
completely destructive interference takes place. Where does the energy go?

In my opinion, the energy is conserved. But I do not know how to explain this. I think it’s up to Poynting-vector but I am not sure

Comment: You have allways maxima and minima in the Michelson experiment,

Comment: I think you mean $E\cos(kx-wt)$, or else $E\exp[i(kx-wt)]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Michelson interferometer produces two beams. One is the usual one typically directed toward a "screen" or photodetector. The other is reflected back toward the source (laser).

If you adjust the mirrors for destructive interference at the output beam, you will have constructive interference at the reflected beam, and vice versa.

Comment: From MIT: [Where does the light go?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRi4dv9KgCg)

Answer (score 0):

These interferometers use beam-splitters that take two incoming beams and produce four outgoing beams, introducing a phase shift on one of them (e.g., one reflected off the exterior surface).

This phase shift means that if you set it up for one pair of outgoing beams to interfere destructively, the other pair will interfere constructively, and so energy is conserved.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_splitter#Phase_shift.